# My sql dsn problem

Tags: mysql, windows-7, odbc, dsn

I want to create DSN of MySql but
IN  windows 7 I don't have driver for Mysql under ODBC->system dsn->add button?
so please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the drivers for MySQL. These drivers should be found with the version of MYSQL you are using.

The Driver link and information to guide you through the process is [Here](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/mysql-odbc.html)

I have not tried it but it looks like windows 7 is not supported, but who knows, never know until you try.